# What do these CloudKit metrics tell (Indexing cost, data usage, limit, metadata storage)

Tags: ios, cloudkit

The ClouKit backend gives me these numbers . What do they tell?

- Should I stop to index some attributes?
- do I use too much data?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In CloudKit you have a limit of data that you can use for your app which starts at 5GB and increases for every user of your app. Besides your actual data indexes also take up some of this storage. If you think you come close to the limits of that free storage, then it might help removing some of the indexes.

Comment: Is there any reference where Apple explains these fields?

Comment: Thanks! Does +21% mean that I'm already _over_ the limit or did I use 21 % _of_ the limit

Comment: I think the +21% means that you will use 21% extra for metadata on top of your normal data. So if you have 4GB of data then you will use about 4.8 GB of CloudKit data. I don't think you can see how much you are really using.